# How to create tabs inside the view page and all of them inside the view pager tabs

Tags: android

I'm trying to create tabs inside the view pager that all of them inside the view pager tabs .
When i use second view pager inside the view pager fragment then 
all tabs are put together.
Please help me.
This mainActivity.java

```
@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);
    mDemoCollectionPagerAdapter =
            new DemoCollectionPagerAdapter(
                    getSupportFragmentManager());
    mViewPager =  findViewById(R.id.pager);
    mViewPager.setAdapter(mDemoCollectionPagerAdapter);
    final android.support.v7.app.ActionBar actionBar = getSupportActionBar();        actionBar.setNavigationMode(android.support.v7.app.ActionBar.NAVIGATION_MODE_TABS);
    android.support.v7.app.ActionBar.TabListener tabListener = new android.support.v7.app.ActionBar.TabListener() {
        @Override
        public void onTabSelected(android.support.v7.app.ActionBar.Tab tab, FragmentTransaction fragmentTransaction) {
            mViewPager.setCurrentItem(tab.getPosition());
        }
        @Override
        public void onTabUnselected(android.support.v7.app.ActionBar.Tab tab, FragmentTransaction fragmentTransaction) {
        }
        @Override
        public void onTabReselected(android.support.v7.app.ActionBar.Tab tab, FragmentTransaction fragmentTransaction) {

        }
    };

    for (int i = 0; i < 3; i++) {
        actionBar.addTab(
                actionBar.newTab()
                        .setText("Tab " + (i + 1))
                        .setTabListener(tabListener));
    }
}
```

This is my fragment where the second viewpager is inside

```
public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater,
                         ViewGroup container, Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    View rootView = inflater.inflate(R.layout.fragment_collection_object, container, false);
    trustCollectionPagerAdapter =new TrustCollectionPagerAdapter(getActivity().getSupportFragmentManager());
    mViewPagerTrust = rootView.findViewById(R.id.paging);
    mViewPagerTrust.setAdapter(trustCollectionPagerAdapter);

    final android.support.v7.app.ActionBar actionBarTrust = ((AppCompatActivity)getActivity()).getSupportActionBar();
    actionBarTrust.setNavigationMode(android.support.v7.app.ActionBar.NAVIGATION_MODE_TABS);

    // Create a tab listener that is called when the user changes tabs.
    android.support.v7.app.ActionBar.TabListener tabListenerTrust = new android.support.v7.app.ActionBar.TabListener() {

        @Override
        public void onTabSelected(android.support.v7.app.ActionBar.Tab tab, FragmentTransaction fragmentTransaction) {
            mViewPagerTrust.setCurrentItem(tab.getPosition());
        }
        @Override
        public void onTabUnselected(android.support.v7.app.ActionBar.Tab tab, FragmentTransaction fragmentTransaction) {
        }
        @Override
        public void onTabReselected(android.support.v7.app.ActionBar.Tab tab, FragmentTransaction fragmentTransaction) {
        }
    };
    for (int i = 0; i < 3; i++) {
        actionBarTrust.addTab(
                actionBarTrust.newTab()
                        .setText("Tab " + (i + 1))
                        .setTabListener(tabListenerTrust));
    }
    return rootView;
}
```

Comment: It's not working or? Any logcats?

Comment: it's not working

Answer (score 0):

[`TabListener`](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/app/ActionBar.TabListener) is depreciated.

Instead, Try replacing:

```
android.support.v7.app.ActionBar.TabListener tabListenerTrust = new android.support.v7.app.ActionBar.TabListener() {
```

With `addOnTabSelectedListener()` as follows:

```
TabLayout tabLayout = (TabLayout) findViewById(R.id.yourtablayoutid);
tabLayout.addOnTabSelectedListener(new TabLayout.OnTabSelectedListener() {

       @Override
        public void onTabSelected(TabLayout.Ta, FragmentTransaction fragmentTransaction) {
            mViewPagerTrust.setCurrentItem(tab.getPosition());
        }
        @Override
        public void onTabUnselected(TabLayout.Ta, FragmentTransaction fragmentTransaction) {
        }
        @Override
        public void onTabReselected(TabLayout.Ta, FragmentTransaction fragmentTransaction) {
        }
    };
```

Comment: If I do this, it will be fine